# CakePHP recursive for beautiful routing - categories, topics, sections, subsections etc

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

First and foremost, I apologise for the length of this question. I wanted to make it as detailed as possible.

I am in the process of developing a web-based application with CakePHP. I have been working on several aspects in the past few weeks and am currently in the process of filling my database tables with lots of information. This should be very easily accessible to the user with beautiful, user-friendly URLs. Assume I have my `Users` and ACOs, AROs etc. all set up. That's all separate from this issue. The relevant aspects of my database for this particular question are as follows:

**Category**: the overarching category (for example, 'Cats')

- Each Category `hasMany` Topics

**Topic**: a particular topic (for example, 'Feeding')

- Each Topic `belongsTo` one Category
- Each Topic `hasMany` Sections

**Section**: a section within a topic (for example, 'Meat')

- Each Section `belongsTo` one Topic
- Each Section `hasMany` Subsections

**Subsection**: a subsection within a section (for example, 'Cooked')

- Each Subsection `belongsTo` one Section

And so on and so forth.

I've configured routing in my `/Config/routes.php` file to include the following:

```
Router::connect('/KnowledgeBase', array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'index'));

Router::connect('/KnowledgeBase/:category', array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view'));

Router::connect('/KnowledgeBase/:category/:topic', array('controller' => 'topics', 'action' => 'view'));

Router::connect('/KnowledgeBase/:category/:topic/:section', array('controller' => 'sections', 'action' => 'view'));

Router::connect('/KnowledgeBase/:category/:topic/:section/:subsection', array('controller' => 'subsections', 'action' => 'view'));
```

As you can see, each URL format links to a particular controller, so that the user can type in a URL such as http://www.mysite.com/KnowledgeBase/Cats/Feeding/Meat/Cooked or http://www.mysite.com/KnowledgeBase/Cats/Grooming and it will land them on the correct page, handled by the correct controller (in these two examples `subsections` and `topics` respectively).

This is where I get a bit stuck. This data needs to be validated. It is quite possible I will have things set up in the future where topics/sections/subsections will have the same name. Using a simple `$params` search for the subsection could theoretically lead to problems if the data isn't recursively validated.

Take, for example, my Dogs category:
http://www.mysite.com/KnowledgeBase/Cats/Feeding/Meat/Cooked
as opposed to:
http://www.mysite.com/KnowledgeBase/Dogs/Feeding/Meat/Cooked

When I land at the particular controller (in this case my `SubsectionsController`) I need to select only the Subsection entitled `Cooked` which belongs in the `Meat` section under the topic `Feeding` in the category entitled `Dogs` (rather than `Cats`, `Leopards`, `Armadillos` or `Dolphins`... I digress).

What is the best way of doing this? So far I can see two potential options:

1. Route all these URLs to one specific controller (e.g. an omniscient `KnowledgeBaseController`) and handle everything from there using a `recursive => 3` call depending on the data requested.
2. Handle this information separately so that my `SubsectionsController` is set to `recursive => -3` and ensure the data has valid parents.
3. Use a mixture of these options - use a central `KnowledgeBaseController` to validate the data using a `recursive => X` find query and then send all this information to the individual controller in question to view.

I'm aware that my code should be as DRY as possible, which would imply I should only use one central controller to validate the URL `$params`. However, categories, topics, sections, subsections have very different layouts and I would rather they are handled by their own controllers, whilst keeping this URL format. What is the best way of going about this? Is there a 'best practises' solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the routes you listed should be in reverse order. The most specific routes at the top and most generic at bottom.

You should be using the option #2. Each level of hierarchy managed by it's own controller. So taking the eg. of the lower most level of your hierarchy SubSections you would have a SubSectionsController for it and do a find on it's SubSection model with proper recursive value to get it's related section, the section's topic and so forth (btw that would be recursive = 3 still, there's no such thing as recursive = -3). So this way you have all the records for the hierarchy and you can validate each url fragment using relevant record of the hierarchy. `$this->request->params` will contain a key for each route element of your route.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and for clarifying that it's actually `recursive = 3`. This is what I had originally planned to do but was concerned about keeping my code as DRY as possible. Thanks for your help!